# Find the value of first input in last table row by class

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value in the first input of the last row of a table using the class name?

The table can have many rows and in every one of them there is an input in the first column with the class "inputtext'.

I thought something like this could work but it does not.

```
$("#tableData tr:last input[class=inputtext]").val();
```

Comment: In your example HTML the "last row" of your table has no cells nor inputs. I'm unclear on exactly what element you need and I have a feeling the HTML you posted isn't a great example

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is what you are looking for?
```
$("#tableData tr:last input[class=inputtext]").first().val();
```
Assuming you have more than one inputs with the same class in the last `tr`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I removed the table. Basically all the rows have a input field in the first column and I want to get the value of the firts input in the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input element has 2 classes, the `input[class=inputtext]` wont work.
Do it like this: `$("#tableData tr:last input.inputtext").val()`.
`input.inputtext` will search for input having atleast one class namely `inputtext`.

```js
console.log($("#tableData tr:last input.inputtext").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="input_1" id="input_1" class="form-control inputtext"/> 
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="input_1" id="input_1" class="form-control inputtext" value="3234"/> </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the value in the first input of the last row of a table using the class name

The `=` operator you used in your css selector only matches an element when the value is exactly the same as the one you searched for.

You can use the [`*=`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) operator instead which will match an element when it contains the searched value.

```js
console.log($("#tableData tr:last input[class*=inputtext]").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                ... 
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control inputtext" value="1234"/> </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control inputtext" value="4321"/> </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the value of the first input in the last row

Use `:last` on row and `:first` on input

```
$("#tableData tr:last input:first").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

The input field is in the first row as your HTML show and you use last so it is not true here it will work with you

```
$("#tableData tr:first input[class=inputtext]").val();
```